# How to find frequencies of pairs of values (A & B) occurring at the same time within groups

Tags: r

I have a dataset consisting: customers, food vendors, and order date .

Customers can order from multiple food vendors within the same day. I need to figure out the frequencies and  %'s  of vendors groups (A & B; A & C, B & C, etc.) that were ordered from the same customer within the same day.

**dataset:**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
  text="Name       Vendor       Order_date
       Bob           A          1-1-2020
       Bob           A          1-1-2020
       Bob           B          1-1-2020
       Joe           A          1-2-2020
       Joe           B          1-2-2020
       Chris         A          1-1-2020
       Chris         B          1-2-2020
       David         C          1-3-2020
       David         A          1-3-2020
       David         B          1-3-2020
")
```

**want:
Freq= 3 for Vendors A & B.**

This result is because Vendors `A` & `B`  were ordered 3 times within the same day from Bob, Joe, David.  Chris does not count because he ordered on different days.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one potential solution using only base `R` functions. The strategy is:

1. Split by day
2. Find unique vendors from which stuff was bought on each day
3. Find all 2 combos of those vendors within days
4. Convert the list to a vector using `unlist`
5. Count using `table`

I define a function called `combinations` to keep things a bit cleaner.

```
dat = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Name       Vendor       Order_date
Bob           A          1-1-2020
Bob           A          1-1-2020
Bob           B          1-1-2020
Joe           A          1-2-2020
Joe           B          1-2-2020
Chris         A          1-1-2020
Chris         B          1-2-2020
David         C          1-3-2020
David         A          1-3-2020
David         B          1-3-2020")

combinations = function(x) {
  out <- combn(unique(x$Vendor), 2)
  apply(out, 2, function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse='+'))
}
dat = split(dat, dat$Order_date)
table(unlist(sapply(dat, combinations)))
#> 
#> A+B A+C B+C 
#>   3   1   1
```